# Javascript array variable undefined using "i" in for loop to access, but available when using absolute value

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, undefined

I've create an array in Javascript designed to hold basic details about a set of upgrades as part of a game I'm making. The upgrades are defined as follows;

```
var Upgrade = {Name:NameIn,
               Description:DescriptionIn,
               Image:ImageIn,
               Purchased:0,
               Visible:false,
               ID:IDIn}
```

I've got a standard for loop that is trying to access these variables. Yet for some reason the Description variable comes up with an "undefined" error when I try to access it using the i variable I've created as part of the loop. i.e. `Upgrades[i].Description` comes up as undefined.

I've checked and all of the other elements such as Name, Image etc can be accessed using the "i" variable. e.g. `Upgrades[i].Name`

Yet if I manually type in what i is equal to as part of my code at the time I try to access Description (e.g having `Upgrades[1]` as oppose to `Upgrades[i]`) it allows access to it.

The array is filled as such;

```
function AddUpgrade(NameIn,DescriptionIn,ImageIn,IDIn){
var Upgrade = {Name:NameIn,
               Description:DescriptionIn,
               Image:ImageIn,
               Purchased:0,
               Visible:false,
               ID:IDIn}
Upgrades.push(Upgrade);

AddUpgrade("Sharpened Rocks","Description",
        "img/upgrades/Caveman2.png","Caveman2Display");
```

Below is the loop that is trying to access the variables to send to an HTML document;

```
for (i = 1; i < Upgrades.length ; i++){
    if (Upgrades[i].Visible == 1){
        document.getElementById("upgrades").innerHTML += "<div class=\"upgrade\" id=\"" + Upgrades[i].ID + 
        "\" onclick=\"ButtonBuyUpgrade(" + i + ")\"><img src=\"" + Upgrades[i].Image + "\"><div class=\"hovertext\" id=\"" 
        + Upgrades[i].ID + "Hover\">" + DisplayUpgradeCost(i) + Upgrades[i].Description + "</div></div>";
    }
}
```

Here is the output from console;

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Description' of undefined
>   inc.js:161 DisplayUpgrade inc.js:161 CalculateUnlocks inc.js:463
>   (anonymous function) inc.js:502 Object {Name: "Sharpened Rocks",
>   Description: "Description", Image: "img/upgrades/Caveman2.png", Purchased: 0,
>   Visible: 1…} Description: "Description" ID: "Caveman2Display" Image:
>   "img/upgrades/Caveman2.png" Name: "Sharpened Rocks" Purchased: 0
>   Visible: 1

And here is the console.dir output;

1: Object
Description: "Description"
ID: "Caveman2Display"
Image: "img/upgrades/Caveman2.png"
Name: "Sharpened Rocks"
Purchased: 0
Visible: 1

All the other elements are also filled in, there are no missing pieces of information.

I'm completely confused by this and have no idea why it's happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: There are 2 `for` loops: `for(;;)` and `for( in )`. Which are you using. The object you posted here might well end up having a member called `Description` with the value `undefined`. It all depends on what the value of `DescriptionIn` was when the object was created...

Comment: Try `console.log(Upgrades)` or `console.log(Upgrades[i])` in your loop.

Comment: Can we see how you fill your array?

Comment: The error means that you are trying to access an element at an index that doesn't exist. `console.dir` your array before the loop and see if there are any holes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this one, it turns out the issue was due to the scope of the `i` variable in my loop coming from another loop the function was being called by, so the program was getting confused. I solved the issue by having the loop say `(var i = 0` to create a local variable called `i` to use.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've created an object. An object is a collection of key:value pairs. An array is a collection of elements ordered by index (starting at 0), denoted by []. To loop through your object try forIn loop:

```
var Upgrade = {
  Name:'NameIn',
  Description:'DescriptionIn',
  Image:'ImageIn',
  Purchased:0,
  Visible:'false',
  ID:'IDIn'
}

for(var i in Upgrade) {
  console.log(Upgrade[i])
}
```

Comment: I need to access specific variables at certain points. It is effectively an array of objects, and I need to access the variables out of sequence of the object variable order.